# jQuery Dialog with internal asp:Button dont want it to close the dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dialog

Question:  How do I stop asp:Button which lives inside an aspx page that is displayed inside a jQuery Dialog from closing the dialog.  I want to keep the dialog open and use it for an info input form for a database table I work with.

I have simple demo code behind that adds two numbers (very crude and elementary) and when I hit the 'Button' to add the numbers it closes the dialog box. It adds the numbers but the dialog box closes.

Calling the dialog:

```
 <script>
        function showDialog() {
            var myDiv = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 500,
                width: 500                
            });
            myDiv.load('EffortSubmittalPage.aspx');
            $("#dialog-form").parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
            myDiv.dialog('open');
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

Content for the page that displays in the dialog:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeaderContent">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="wrapper" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table id="Table1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="300" border="0">

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server">First Number:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server">Second Number:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSecondNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server">Sum:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSum" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1"
                            runat="server"
                            Text="Add Numbers"
                            OnClick="Button1_Click"></asp:Button>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Content for the code behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var intTotal = 0;
            var intFirstNumber = 0;
            var intSecondNumber = 0;

            intFirstNumber = int.Parse(txtFirstNumber.Text);
            intSecondNumber = int.Parse(txtSecondNumber.Text);

            intTotal = intFirstNumber + intSecondNumber;
            txtSum.Text = intTotal.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Any advice is welcome..
Andy.

Comment: What is the content of `EffortSubmittalPage.aspx`? Is that the code which you have given ( e.g. having `asp:Content .. `?

Comment: Yes the asp effort submittal page is what comes up in the dialog window... the aspx..

Comment: I can see the error, you are loading content of aspx to a `DIV` and on button click you are submitting the page, that made the div for jquery dialog go away, but if you can do register.startupscript with script as `.dialog.show ..` -- something similar, it might work.

Comment: Still working on this one.  Thanks Arindam...  I might drop the attempt to use the asp inside the dialog and just run jQuery and JavaScript for it.

Comment: I would not recommend trying this.  The use of an entire aspx page inside a dialog seems to be more trouble than it is worth.  I was able to go back and use straight jQuery to accomplish what I wanted to do.

Comment: It depends on your requirement, if you can manage withour aspx , then it is fine with what you tried.